# .index() show index of both similar elements from a list

Tags: python, indexing

Let's say I have a list

```
list = [1,2,1,3,4,5]
```

How do I find the index of both the `1` from the list using `.index()` function in python(or any other methods)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#enumerate) instead:

```
>>> lst = [1,2,1,3,4,5]
>>> index_one = [i for i, x in enumerate(lst) if x == 1]
>>> index_one
[0, 2]
```